# Multi insert function exceut one after another

Tags: java, mysql, mybatis

I have a program the calls insert function like in the following.

```
insertOrder();
for(int i = 0; i < 3 ; i++){
     insertItem();
}
```

**My insert statements use `mybatis`.**

If the `inserOrder()` is error so the program will stop. 
But `insertItem()` error the `insertOrder` is already executed and insert into the database.

I want to control that if any of these insert is error, nothing will insert into database. Can you help me to do it?

Comment: You need to learn about transactions it seems. Currently you are using auto commit - which should really be avoided for exactly this reason.

Comment: can you help me how to do it. I am using mysql database.

Comment: By default `sessionFactory.openSession()` is not auto-commit.
In mybatis config, if using `transactionManager type="JDBC"`, then you must call `session.commit()` at the end of your code, 
if using `transactionManager type="MANAGED"`, the container will commit for you.